# Convert XML to XML using XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

XML Input File:

```
<employees>
    <employee empId ="5001">
        <firstName>Ram</firstName>
        <middleName>Prakash</middleName>
        <lastName>Sharma</lastName>
        <department>IT</department>
        <address>    
            <address1>H7 H Block</address1>
            <address2>Sector 63</address2>    
            <city>Noida</city>    
            <state>UP</state>    
            <pincode>201301</pincode>    
        </address>    
        <dateOfJoining>01/01/2017</dateOfJoining >    
        <grade>R</grade>    
    </employee>    
</employees>
```

The XML Input File is converted to XML Output File. The firstName, middleName and lastName tags of XML Input File is merged into name tag in XML Ouput File and the address1, address2, city, state and pincode tags of XML Input File is merged into address tag in XML Ouput File.

XML Output File:

```
<employees>    
    <employee empId ="5001">    
        <name>Ram Prakash Sharma</name>    
        <department>IT</department>    
        <address>H7 H Block Sector 63 Noida UP 201301</address>    
        <dateOfJoining>01/01/2017</dateOfJoining >    
        <grade>R</grade>    
    </employee>    
</employees>
```

I have almost converted the code but I am struggling with empId here. I have manually entered the empId in XSLT file. Can someone please help me?

XSLT File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
    <xsl:template match="employees">
        <employees>
            <employee empId="5001">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </employee>
        </employees>
    </xsl:template>    
    <xsl:template match="employee">    
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="concat(firstName, ' ', middleName, ' ', lastName)" />
        </name>    
        <department>
            <xsl:value-of select="department" />
        </department>    
        <address>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/address1" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/address2" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/city" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/state" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/pincode" />
        </address>    
        <dateOfJoining>
            <xsl:value-of select="dateOfJoining" />
        </dateOfJoining>    
        <grade>
            <xsl:value-of select="grade" />
        </grade>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shift the `employee` element to the `employee` template and use the `{@empId}` attribute value template to set the `empId` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="employees">
    <employees>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </employees>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="employee">
    <employee id="{@empId}">
      <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(firstName, ' ', middleName, ' ', lastName)" />
      </name>
      <department>
        <xsl:value-of select="department" />
      </department>
      <address>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/address1" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/address2" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/city" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/state" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/pincode" />
        </address>
      <dateOfJoining>
        <xsl:value-of select="dateOfJoining" />
      </dateOfJoining>
      <grade>
        <xsl:value-of select="grade" />
      </grade>
    </employee>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```